# The grammar in Vertx HttpServerRequest

Tags: java, vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am quite new in Java, and I am learning Vertx recently, I can't understand how the following code works:

```java
@Override
public void start() {
    vertx.createHttpServer()
        .requestHandler(req -> req.response()
          .end("hello"))
        .listen(8080);
}
```

My question is: why the parameter `req` do not need to declare a type and where is this req come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's break it into pieces.

### Create HTTP Server

Creating instance `HttpSever` using our `Vertx` instance.

```
HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
```

### Define request handler

Now, for our `HttpServer` we can define handler for incoming requests.

We can use for this `HttpServer#requestHandler(Handler<HttpServerRequest> handler)` [1]. This method takes an instance of `Handler<HttpRequest>`.

So, we can define our instance of `Handler<HttpServerRequest>` as follows:

```
private static class MyRequestHandler implements Handler<HttpServerRequest> {

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpServerRequest req) {
        req.response().end("Hello");
    }
}
```

This handler will just print `"Hello"` for every incoming request.

Now we can associate instance of `MyReqesutHandler` with our `httpServer` instance.

```
httpServer.requestHandler(new MyRequestHandler())
```

and start the HTTP server on port `8080`

```
httpServer.listen(8080);
```

### Refactor using lambdas

Note that, Handler is a so called functional interface [2] instead of defining whole class we can pass a lambda function [3] directly to `httpServer.requestHandler()`.

We can avoid lots of boilerplate code.

So by using lambda we do not need to define whole class, it's enough to do:

```
httpServer.requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("Hello"));
```

Now because JAVA compiler knows the `httpServer.requestHandler()` takes an instance of `Handler<HttpServerRequest>`, it can **infer** type of `req` in compile type, just by looking at method declaration.

### Refactor using Fluent API

As vert.x promotes Fluet API [4], we can chain method without need of intermediate variables.

```
vertx.createHttpServer()
      .requestHandler(req -> req.response().end("hello"))
      .listen(8080);
```

---

I strongly recommend you to look at **Java lambda tutorials** and get nice feeling for them, as they are used pretty much not in Vert.x only but in Java world everytwhere.

Have fun!

---

[1] https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/core/http/HttpServer.html#requestHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-

[2] https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-functional-interfaces

[3] https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/

[4] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface